# Is is possible to add a input dialog box like how java has JOptionPane

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this application that I'm building and I was wondering if its possible to add a input dialog box like how Java has the JOptionPane.

```
<TextBlock Text="Please choose if you are renting or buying a property" Margin="0 10 0 0" />
        <ComboBox SelectionChanged="PropertyDropDown_SelectionChanged" x:Name="PropertyDropDown" Padding="2">
            <ComboBoxItem>Renting accommodation</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Buying a property</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
```

In the above code I have a combo box in WPF where the user can decide to either choose to rent a property or buy a property I was wondering if its possible to when a uses selects an option if its possible to prompt the user with a input dialog box where he can enter the rent amount or when he chooses to buy a property he can enter the purchase price of the property,the interest rate and the duration of the loan.

I have added the event and I am able to display a message box displaying the selected choice.

```
private void PropertyDropDown_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Your choice" + PropertyDropDown.SelectedItem);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the way to get this behavior with WPF is to create a window and call it with ShowDialog().  It's slightly less convenient than the Java Joption pane.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/windows/dialog-boxes-overview?view=netdesktop-6.0

*posting this here because this thread is a top google search result and it may help others looking to make the transition from java/swing to c#/wpf*